# Facebook Session not getting opened through IOS FacebookApp

Tags: ios, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to incorporate the login with FB in my app .

The problem I am facing is , FB login is successful if the FB app is not installed on the device . 
But if the FB app is installed on the device , the session is not getting opened .

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.13 and heres the code I am using for the login activity is as follows :

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

self.please_wait_view.hidden=NO;
// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for basic_info permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes",@"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         //NSLog(@"%@",[session accessTokenData]);
         fb_access_token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session accessTokenData]];
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
}
```

}
This is the method for Session state changed :

```
// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");
    /    / Show the user the logged-in UI
        //[self userLoggedIn];
        return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed
        NSLog(@"Session closed");
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        //[self userLoggedOut];
    }

// Handle errors
if (error){
    NSLog(@"Error");
    NSString *alertText;
    NSString *alertTitle;
    // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
        alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
        alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
         NSLog(@"%@",alertText);
    } else {

        // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
        if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

            // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
            alertTitle = @"Session Error";
            alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
            //[self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            NSLog(@"%@",alertText);

            // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
            // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
            // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
        } else {
            //Get more error information from the error
            NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

            // Show the user an error message
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
            //[self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            NSLog(@"%@",alertText);
        }
    }
    // Clear this token
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    // Show the user the logged-out UI
    //[self userLoggedOut];
}
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

try with this one hope this will help you

Comment: Already have this in the code . When m app launches the fb app for authentication , it throws an error code of 100 . But works fine if I delete the FB app .

Answer (score 0):

Ok So after a day and a half wasted ... I finally figured out a solution .

I just changed the app that I was using for FB login and replaced the new fb app ID and bundleID and the url scheme in the .plist file and it seems to be working fine . 
Dunno what caused the issue though cause the app I was using previously for login is almost identical to the new one !